# Is there an extension for Google Chrome that lets me bind keyboard shortcuts to arbitrary javascript?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I think the title says it all--an example use case would be enabling me to trigger bookmarklets by keyboard shortcut instead of Bookmark Bar or Search Engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few solutions. You can try [BookmarkBar Hotkeys](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/epljiamjefebpckdcbjelbbmepgancpg) or [Shortcut Manager](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/mgjjeipcdnnjhgodgjpfkffcejoljijf). You could also give [JavaScript Tester](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/fkdonpadcmdinahpmloinegkgklkckfa) a go for testing.

Also, instead of using bookmarklets as normal, what you can do is to create a Search Engine (right-click Omnibar, select Edit Search Engines), then create an entry, providing a keyword and using the JavaScript as the URL. Then you can use the keyword in the Omnibar to trigger the bookmarklet.